# Commit to master in terminal doesn't recognize my active username

Tags: git, github

I'm attempting to make the initial commit to my organizations repo. 
When I enter the command:

```
$git push -u origin master
```

This error message is returned:

> remote: Permission to (my-work-username)/Team-Website.git denied to (my-personal-username).
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/(my-work-username)/Team-Website.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I've changed my username and email using:

```
$git config --global user.name "my-work-username"
$git config --global user.email "my-work-email"
```

And verified them using:

```
$git config --list
```

Which returned:

> user.name=(my-work-username)
>   user.email=(my-work-email)

So I want to push my directory to the repo, although the 403 error occurs, preventing this, because it doesn't recognize my current username as matched the authorized username for that repo.

What should I try to get github to recognize the authorized and active usernames match?

Comment: `git config` only affects local stuff, like the information included in new commits. Authentication is done via SSH key or (in your case, since you're using HTTPS) a user and password that you should be prompted for. Are you using two-factor authentication? Because if you are you can't use your regular GitHub password.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration from `git config` affects your local settings, such as the name and email that show up on your commits. They do not affect the username used for github.

Check the URL of your `origin`:

`git remote -v`

You will likely see something like `origin  https://github.com/GithubUsername/GithubRepoName.git (push)`. Then you can add your Github username for HTTPS authentication into the url, by changing it, like this:

`git remote set-url origin https://github_user@github.com/Githubusername/GithubReponame.git`

Then, when you push or fetch, you'll be prompted for the password.

This assumes you're using HTTPS authentication and do not have 2FA enabled.